# Find all hash tags within a text

Tags: actionscript-3

I need to find all hash tags in this text using ActionScript 3 (AS3):

> Lorem ipsum dolor #sit_amet, consetetur
>   sadipscing, sed #diam-nonumy
>   eirmod tempor #invidunt ut labore #et

What's a good method to do this?
Thanks
Frank

Comment: I never heard of a "hashtag" before, but a quick search shows up lots of twitter junk. So with that being said the twitter docs should at least have a list of them, and that is where you need to start your list of "hashtag's" then you can parse them out once you have your compiled list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your data:
var data:String = "Lorem ipsum dolor #sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed #diam-nonumy eirmod tempor #invidunt ut labore #et";

// this regular expression will match most "normal" characters, add more as needed
// it will stop at the first whitespace or linebreak it hits
var regex:RegExp = /(\#[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]*)/g;

// this object will be used to store our results
var result:Object;

// now, we run the regex until it returns null, 
// that means there's nothing more that matches
while (result = regex.exec(data)) {
    // since we're not using groups or anything, all we want is the 0 in the object
    trace(result[0]);
}
```

This will trace:

```
#sit_amet
#diam-nonumy
#invidunt
#et
```

Comment: You are in fact grouping your whole match, and you'll match a single hash as well. Black-listing instead of white-listing might be easier too, here's the start of such a regex: /#[^\s,]+/g

Comment: Thank you very much! RegExp is very interesting. Is there also a smart way to delete the found tags from the text afterwards?

Comment: i've responded to this question with a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborate more on "find" because I'm not sure what you want to do with them.

That said, this may meet your needs:

```
var str:String = "Lorem ipsum dolor #sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed #diam-nonumy eirmod tempor #invidunt ut labore #et";
var array:Array = str.split("#");
```

Your array will contain the following - which you can prepend with a hash again to get a hashtag:

0: Lorem ipsum dolor 
1: sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed 
2: diam-nonumy eirmod tempor 
3: invidunt ut labore 
4: et

If this isn't quite what you were after then you may need to look into regular expressions which are way beyond my scope of knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

> RE:  Is there also a smart way to
>   delete the found tags from the text
>   afterwards?

do you just want to delete the actual hash-tag or the hash-tag and its tagged word?

this will remove only the hash-tag from the string:

```
myString.replace(new RegExp("#", "g"), ""));
```

while this will remove the hash-tag and its tagged word from the string:

```
myString.replace(new RegExp("#\\w*", "g"), "")
```

a complete tutorial and reference for regular expressions can be found here:  http://www.regular-expressions.info/

--

edit:

it's a bit complicated since you want to replace parts of the string between hash tags while the entire string is essentially between hash tags throughout.  therefore, using a simple regular expression lookaround will not be foolproof without writing your own string parser.

but something like this could work:

```
var stringData:String = "#Lorem # et #ipsum dolor #sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed #diam et #word# #_hello_# #-word# #word# #1a# #2WORD2# #2012# #word-3# #word_3# #word 3#";

trace(stringData.replace(new RegExp("#(.*?)#", "g"), ""));
```

Comment: I don't get it to work. I'm trying to remove all words that are inbetween two hash characters. This is my AS3 code: `var mystring = "#Lorem # et #ipsum dolor #sit_amet, consetetur sadipscing, sed #diam et #word# #_hello_# #-word# #word# #1a# #2WORD2# #2012# #word-3# #word_3# #word 3#";
//
var regex:RegExp = /(\#[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]*#)/g;
var myresult:Object;
//
function  removewords() {
while (myresult = regex.exec(mystring)) {
mystring = mystring.replace(myresult[0], "")
}
//
trace(mystring)
}
//
removewords()
` It seems that there is a problem with the number ones. Any ideas?